# Make HTML divs not move when rescaling browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now my HTML page has multiple divs. This is how it looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="thecss.css">
    <title>Information</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img src = "the.jpg" class = "thelogo" width="150" height="50"></src>

        <div id="barChart">
            <h1 id = "barcharthead"> Information One </h1>
            <canvas id="income"></canvas>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
                var browserwidth = (window.outerWidth * .347222222222);
                var browserheight = (window.outerHeight * 0.4028868175);
                canvas.width = browserwidth;
                canvas.height = browserheight;
            </script>
        </div>

        <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="getbytesinfo.js"></script>
        <script src="makebarchart.js"></script>

        <div id="pieChart"></div>           
            <script src="getinfo.js"></script>
            <script src="makepiechart.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, my two divs are currently overlapping with one another. I thought adding the following CSS would solve the problem, and it did for the most part:

```
#wrapper {
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
#pieChart {
        position:absolute;
        left:1%;
 }

#barChart {
        position:absolute;
        right:1%;
}
```

but when I try scaling the browser, the divs just overlap with one another again. Is there anyway I can make it so the divs are basically stuck to the screen? In other words, even if a user starts minimizing the browser size, the charts don't move at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Give your wrapper a fixed min-width: (e.g. 1000px), so if the browser resizes, it gets a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: So change the position to fixed and add a min-width? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Never mind I dont think I need to change the position, but the min-width part worked! Thanks!

Comment: So does doing this make it so that if the screen is less than 1000px, the div wont even load? @StevenMoseley